# PushViewController details?

Tags: ios, swift

What I am trying to do is a custom animation of pushing ViewController from the **left** side.
I have created my custom transitioning delegate and I provide my custom animation, and everything works fine (new view slides from the left side).
The only problem is that push animation in iOS isn't only about sliding a view from the right side. The VC being obscured is also slightly moving in the same directions as the VC being pushed. Also, navigation bar kinda blinks. I can of course try to imitate this behaviour by guessing what the parameters should be (for example how much the VC being obscured moves on different iPhones), but maybe it is possible to find the values somewhere?
Help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning protocol abiding object

```
class CustomHorizontalSlideTransition: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {

    var operation: UINavigationControllerOperation = .Push

    convenience init(operation: UINavigationControllerOperation) {
        self.init()
        self.operation = operation
    }

    func transitionDuration(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> NSTimeInterval {
        return 0.5
    }

    func animateTransition(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {

        let containerView = transitionContext.containerView()

        let disappearingVC = transitionContext.viewControllerForKey(UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey)!
        let appearingVC = transitionContext.viewControllerForKey(UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey)!

        let bounds = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds

        if self.operation == .Push {
            appearingVC.view.frame = CGRectOffset(bounds, -bounds.size.height, 0)
            containerView!.addSubview(disappearingVC.view)
            containerView!.addSubview(appearingVC.view)
        } else {
            appearingVC.view.frame = bounds
            disappearingVC.view.frame = bounds
            containerView!.addSubview(appearingVC.view)
            containerView!.addSubview(disappearingVC.view)
        }

        UIView.animateWithDuration(transitionDuration(transitionContext),
            delay: 0.0,
            options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut,
            animations: { () -> Void in

                if self.operation == .Push {
                    appearingVC.view.frame = bounds
                } else {
                    disappearingVC.view.frame = CGRectOffset(bounds, -bounds.size.width, 0)
                }

            }) { (complete) -> Void in
                transitionContext.completeTransition(true)
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your "From" and "To" view controllers, set the navigationController's delegate to self in view ViewDidAppear

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    navigationController?.delegate = self
}
```

The in both view controllers, override the following to provide a `transitionAnimatedTransition` delegate method and return the protocol abiding instance for your animation

```
override func transitionAnimatedTransition(operation: UINavigationControllerOperation) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        return CustomHorizontalSlideTransition(operation: operation)
}
```